# Mediaplayer not playing sound before it finished

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have a button in my app that should make a sound each time it is clicked. The problem is that it plays only if I wait until the first sound finishes. I need it to play it no matter how fast the button is repeatedly clicked. The file I am using is `.mp3` and is located in the `res\raw` folder in my Android Studio project.

I initialized it as:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.sound);
```

My initial code for the button click was simply

```
player.start();
```

Tried to play with the functions as follows but had the same problem:

```
if (player.isPlaying()) {
    player.stop();
}
player.start();
```

```
if (player.isPlaying()) {
    player.pause();
    player.restart();
}
player.start();
```

```
if (player.isPlaying()) {
    player.restart();
}
player.start();
```

Using `player.prepare()` or `player.prepareAsync()` causes `java.lang.IllegalStateException` error, possibly because the initialization as I used it is already calling `prepare()` behind the scenes.

How to achieve sound immediately when function invokes? not necsassarily using `MediaPlayer`. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You must also reset the player after stopping it:

```
...
player.stop();
player.reset();
...
```

[image]